# Bootstrap3 non-integer width and responsive images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-images

I'm curious to know how you resolve the following problem.

Using Bootstrap 3 with 24 columns and grid-gutter to 30px.
In wide display, I use col-7 for the sidebar left and col-17 for the main content. The problem is bootstrap is calculating the widths with percentage. So I have 339.5px (29.16667%) for the sidebar, and 824.484px (70.83333%) for the content.

```html
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-lg-7">[sidebar]</aside>
  <div class="col-lg-17">[main content]</div>
</div>
```

Now, I use some scripts like lazysizes and lazyaspectratio to lazy-load my pictures and have the image container kept the same dimensions even if the image is not already loaded. With lazyaspectratio, the width must be 100% to recalculate the height to keep.

BUT... because there is a but... if my main content is 824.484px width, the picture is 824.484px width too, and picture quality is bad. Assuming my picture display must be 824px, the final picture display is shitty and I lost quality, even if the ratio is respected.

My question is : how to bypass this problem with img > width=100% ?

I saw on several threads that people "fix" the width of the row children, like this :

```css
div.row > aside.col-lg-7 {
  width: 340px;
}
div.row > div.col-lg-17 {
  max-width: 824px;
}
```

It seems a good solution to keep img > width = 100% and have integer columns width, but with this solution, I must add lot of css rules to manage for multiples col-* and multiples media-queries...

And you ? how do you solve this kind of problem ? Because I think using img-responsive class with width=100% cause quality loss on percentage based width with Bootstrap 3... I'm sure that I'm not the only one to encounter this problem.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: `col-17`??? Bootstrap has 12 column layout.

Comment: Bootstrap can be customised for have more grids etc... will max-width: note work then? I don't think  understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

Andrejs: You can customize bootstrap at: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

titouille: You could create a Javascript that rounds the images widths down based on their classes or parents.

For each image element you read in the width of the col or parent and set it (rouded down to 1 px) as it's max-width

Comment: For Andrejs : like I said, based on $grid-columns = 24, so 17 + 7 = 24.
For AdamJeffers : it's a good idea to use max-width, I didn't realize it take precedence on width value. Solution can be to set max-width for pictures in wide, normal and tablet modes (because mobile use 100% width in all cases). 
For Alari : it would be better without using javascript to reset sizes.

Comment: I believe you're already using javascript to set the sizes when using the lazysizes and lazyaspectratio, which is why I proposed this :)